# No AirPlay on 6 Plus

Tags: ios, airport, airplay

My new iPhone 6 Plus (iOS 8) doesn't show an option for AirPlay in the control centre, and on the few occasions that it does, it only shows itself as a target.... Not my Airport Express. I can't see the airport in airport utility either.

My iPhone 4S (iOS 7) and iPad Air (iOS 8) both consistently see the Airport without problem. So does my MacBook (Mountain Lion).

Have I configured something wrongly on the new phone? Is there anything I can change?

All are on the same (fairly simple) WiFi. Even more bizarrely, the iPhone can't see the Airport as an AirPlay... Even while connected to it directly via the Airport's own wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: my time was set to manual, not automatic, and a day in the past.

This was preventing Airplay from working, along with iMessage and Facetime.